# Is it possible to redirect a GitHub pages site to a host with a url-path?

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I would like to redirect users from https://danskii.github.io/Toronto-Bike-Fixit-Map/ to danielpuiatti.com/Toronto-Bike-Fixit-Map/

I was able to set up a custom domain to redirect to danielpuiatti.com with a CNAME, but I can't figure out how to get it to redirect to danielpuiatti.com/Toronto-Bike-Fixit-Map/

My current CNAME

```
danielpuiatti.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could redirect them directly using:

```
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=https://example.com/">
</head>
```

if they need to be logged before you redirect them, you can turn this into an jsx condition such as

```
loggedIn? <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=https://example.com/"> : null
```

*this meta tag also works outside the head*

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple javascript code to redirect your current page:

```
window.location.replace("https://danielpuiatti.com");
```

Read more: [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)